# What's the easiest way to redirect unsupported browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser

I am coding a site that supports IE9, Firefox 23, Chrome 29 and safari 5.1.

Rather than graceful depreciation, I simply want to redirect all other browsers to a separate webpage that says "Sorry buddy. Time to be a man and get a real browser.".

What's the simplest way to do this with the least amount of code?

Comment: Instead of checking for a specific browser version, you should really check for capabilities and redirect if these capabilities are not met.

Comment: Read this article: http://www.pontikis.net/tip/?id=27

Comment: and this http://css-tricks.com/browser-detection-is-bad/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Feature detection is the way to go, and not browser sniffing, but to provide you with the answer you seem to be looking for, I cooked up this :

```
var browser = (function(){
    var ua = navigator.userAgent, 
        M  = ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*([\d\.]+)/i) || [],
        tem;

    if(/trident/i.test(M[1])){
        tem =  /\brv[ :]+(\d+(\.\d+)?)/g.exec(ua) || [];
        return ['ie', (tem[1] || '')];
    }
    M = M[2] ? [M[1].toLowerCase(), M[2]]:[navigator.appName.toLowerCase(), navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
    if((tem = ua.match(/version\/([\.\d]+)/i))!= null) M[2] = tem[1];
    return M;
})();

var supported = {
    'ie' : 9,
    'chrome' : 29,
    'safari' : 5.1
}

if (supported[browser[0]] <= (browser[0]=='safari' ? parseFloat(browser[1]) : parseInt(browser[1],10))) {
    alert('Your browser is OK !');
}else{
    window.location.href = 'http://browsehappy.com/';
}
```

It's untested in all browsers but the latest chrome, you'll have to test it yourself, and tweak it to your needs, but it should return an array with the browsername and browserversion that you can check to see if it matches your requirements.

And again, feature detection is generally the way to go, browser sniffing isn't.

Comment: thanks, why is feature detection better than browser sniffing? Wouldn't that mean I need to test every function I use in my code?

Comment: Because for browser detection, you need to keep the detection script up to date. If a browser signature changes, you won't detect it correctly any more. IE11 for example just changed their signature and old browser detection scripts will break as a result of it.  In addition, how will you handle all the really odd browsers (Lynx, Maxthon, NetSurf, Retawq, Rockmelt, etc.)?  With feature detection you know what your browser needs to be capable of and if it isn't it will redirect.

Comment: @Steve Thanks, so is it best practice to test for every function in my code?

Comment: @alias51 It generally boils down to detecting the latest feature all your target browsers support, for example [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) was one of the latest ES5 additions.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Modernizer](http://modernizr.com/):

Its a really easy js plugin that allows you to detect, redirect, and otherwise support users coming from less then current browsers. The link above should give you all you need to know.

From thier site:

> Modernizr makes it easy for you to write conditional JavaScript and
>   CSS to handle each situation, whether a browser supports a feature or
>   not. It’s perfect for doing progressive enhancement easily.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking to redirect the browser though, this is graceful degradation which I don't want.